# Better code for reversing and joining matrices

Tags: matrix, code-review

I am writing a function to reverse a matrix and join the reversed version to the original one, making a new matrix which I call `A`. And after doing this, I reverse `A` and join it with original `A` to get the result I want.

I have written my code like this:

```
matJoin[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
  Module[{A, W, H}, 
    A = Join[mat, Reverse /@ mat, 2];
    {W, H} = Dimensions[mat];
    Join[A, ArrayReshape[Reverse @ Flatten[A], {H, 2 W}]]]
```

For example, for a random matrix `mat=RandomInteger[10, {4, 4}]`shown as below:

> {{10, 0, 3, 6}, {1, 0, 1, 9}, {2, 2, 6, 9}, {4, 5, 7, 4}}

Applying it to the `matJoin` function I wrote: `matJoin[mat]`

The output was shown as below and it had served my purpose:

> {{10, 0, 3, 6, 6, 3, 0, 10}, {1, 0, 1, 9, 9, 1, 0, 1}, {2, 2, 6, 9, 9,
>   6, 2, 2}, {4, 5, 7, 4, 4, 7, 5, 4}, {4, 5, 7, 4, 4, 7, 5, 4}, {2,
>   2, 6, 9, 9, 6, 2, 2}, {1, 0, 1, 9, 9, 1, 0, 1}, {10, 0, 3, 6, 6, 3,
>   0, 10}}

But my problems are:

1. It only works for matrices with dimensions of even orders. If the `W` and `H` have odd values, the code doesn't work properly.
2. I am thinking there is a better way to write the function to make it run faster.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to edit this question to include an example of data which produces a wrong result and which shows what the right result would be for the data provided.

Comment: Thanks, already updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[m_?MatrixQ] := Module[{d = Dimensions@m,  rows, cols},
 rows = Join[#, 1 + d[[1]] - #] &@Range[d[[1]]];
 cols = Join[#, 1 + d[[2]] - #] &@Range[d[[2]]]; 
 m[[rows, cols]]];

f @ Array[Subscript[a, Row @ {##}]&, {4, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
f @ Array[Subscript[a, Row @ {##}]&, {3, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Using Henrik's timing setup `f` is is about twice as fast as `matJoin2`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}];

r = matJoin[mat]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.022

```
r2 = matJoin2[mat]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.014

```
r3 = f[mat]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0064

```
r == r2 == r3
```

> True

**Update:** A faster version of Mike Honeychurch's `g`:

```
g2[mat_] := With[{a=Join[mat, Reverse[mat, 2], 2] }, Join[a, Reverse @ a]]

r4 = g[mat]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.090

```
r5 = g2[mat]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.046

```
r == r2 == r3 == r4 == r5
```

> True

**Note:** Timings on Wolfram Cloud, Version "11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

Comment: Ah, very good idea to boil it down to one single read-and-copy request.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking about joining and reversing why not use `Join` and `Reverse` and use level specs?

```
mat = {{10, 0, 3, 6}, {1, 0, 1, 9}, {2, 2, 6, 9}, {4, 5, 7, 4}}

Join[Join[mat, Reverse[mat, 2], 2],Reverse@Join[mat, Reverse[mat, 2], 2]]

(*
{{10, 0, 3, 6, 6, 3, 0, 10}, {1, 0, 1, 9, 9, 1, 0, 1}, {2, 2, 6, 9, 9,
   6, 2, 2}, {4, 5, 7, 4, 4, 7, 5, 4}, {4, 5, 7, 4, 4, 7, 5, 4}, {2, 
  2, 6, 9, 9, 6, 2, 2}, {1, 0, 1, 9, 9, 1, 0, 1}, {10, 0, 3, 6, 6, 3, 
  0, 10}}
*)
```

Test 2

```
mat = Array[Subscript[a, Row@{##}] &, {3, 5}]
```

[image]

```
g[mat_] :=Join[Join[mat, Reverse[mat, 2], 2],Reverse@Join[mat, Reverse[mat, 2], 2]]
```

or

```
h[mat_] := Module[{mat2 = Join[mat, Reverse[mat, 2], 2]},
  Join[mat2, Reverse@mat2]
  ]
```

Timing on my machine has this solution the fastest as well as the most intuitive

Answer (score 1):

This one appears to be twice as fast:

```
matJoin2[mat_?MatrixQ] := Module[{m, n, a, b},
  {m, n} = Dimensions[mat];
  a = mat[[Range[n, 1, -1]]];
  b = mat[[All, Range[m, 1, -1]]];
  ArrayFlatten[{{mat, b}, {a, b[[Range[m, 1, -1]]]}}]
  ]
```

Test:

```
mat = RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}];
r = matJoin[mat]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 = matJoin2[mat]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r == r2
```

> 0.0276
>
> 0.014
>
> True